# Complex query stored procedure or Eloquent

Tags: mysql, eloquent

is it possible to create this query using ORM Eloquent? I'm not an Eloquent expert...

```
SELECT
    users.id as user_id,
    sales.id as sales_id,
    stores.id as storeId,
    chainstores.id as chainstoreId,
    CONCAT(customers.firstname, ' ', customers.lastname) as name,
    users.name as seller,
    sales.cupom,
    sales.price,
    sales.redem_value,
    chainstores.name as chanstore,
    stores.name as store,
    IF(
       (SELECT balances.id FROM balances WHERE balances.chainstore_id = chainstores.id AND balances.customer_id = customers.id LIMIT 1),
       '0.00',
        (SELECT redeemrules.redeem FROM redeemrules WHERE redeemrules.chainstore_id = chainstores.id LIMIT 1)
     ) as balance,
    sales.created_at,
    sales.redemption_date
FROM customers
    INNER JOIN sales ON customers.id = sales.customer_id
    INNER JOIN users ON sales.user_id = users.id
    INNER JOIN chainstores ON chainstores.id = customers.chainstore_id
    INNER JOIN stores ON stores.id = customers.store_id
WHERE
    chainstores.id  = _chainstoreId AND
    stores.id       = _storeId AND 
    DATE(sales.created_at) = _day ORDER BY sales.created_at DESC;
```

about performance, this query has some variations depending on the "where" parameters, is it feasible to create a stored procedure and just make the call using Eloquent, or can I just use it to create these types of queries?

I have these variations:

```
MONTH(sales.created_at) = MONTH(_month) 
AND YEAR(sales.created_at) = YEAR(_month) 
ORDER BY sales.created_at DESC;
```

and

```
YEAR(sales.created_at) = YEAR(_year) 
ORDER BY sales.created_at DESC;
```

Tables

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: for performance questions we need to know the tables including indexes anhd a EXPLAIN of the query

Comment: these tables have relationships with each other, I created these relationships in the model, this query shows the sales of a certain store, it is possible to filter by date range, daily, months and year, there is an inter condition that shows if the customer has a bonus balance (balance) this amount is determined by the store, so I check if this "Bonus" has already been used by the customer

Comment: As i wrote in my commentm, the performance is influenced by the selected indexes, as long as we don't know them we can say anything, the EXPLAIN will show us which of these indexes are used, qand maybe there is a better choice, so an experimnent with different FORCE INDEX hepls if mysql chooses the wrong one

Comment: I use these tables to show the sales of each store...

Comment: every ON clause you need an index for the columns and also for the where clause, if you have more than one column make a combined index, then test with EXPLAIN if the are choosen

Comment: If it was me, I'd start over, with the sql, and after having reviewed this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: `balances`, and `redeemrules` probably should part of a `left join` rather than a result. Is there really going to be more than one match? If so which result do you want?

Comment: @danblack balance expect only one result, but depends on two conditions: first - if the store has redemption value, second - if the customer has already redeemed

Comment: even with them in a join, you can still use and `IF` in the `select` results. `balances.id` will be a `NULL` if there are no matches on the left join, and the `redemption` values are there otherwise. This will also be easier to fit in with the `eloquent` framework

Comment: @danblack I almost achieved this, first I'm trying to understand how to select the fields, I got it using `with(['model:fields','model:fields'])`, I'm trying to make the `balance` condition based on the result of the relationship, it seems that doing this query in eloquent is better than creating a procedure..